# Размещение сайта на хостинг reg.ru

Tags: php, wordpress

столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Был сайт на хостинге, в свое время не успели хостинг оплатить и он слетел, но осталась возможность скачать полный бэкап сайта с БД. Решил заново выгрузить всё на хостинг, выложил файлы сайта и получил следующие ошибки при попытке отобразить сайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Постарался сам найти решение, но увы, всё варианты, которые предлагались на просторах интернета мне не помогли, ни перепечатать строки с **continue** на **continue 2**, ни выключить показ ошибок  добавлением - `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`.Быть может кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Это предупреждения от PHP, а не WordPress. [Выключайте предупреждения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987579/remove-warning-messages-in-php) через error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE), но еще лучше исправьте ошибки, на которые они указывают (если есть возможность).

Comment: @DanielProtopopov куда именно следует вбить данный код? в index.php?

Comment: Скорее в [wp-config.php](https://aristath.github.io/blog/wp-hide-php-errors)

Comment: [Полетели сериалы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562) + возможно побилась/неправильная кодировка

Comment: Возможно у вас версия php другая стала. Попробуйте поэкспериментировать с этим